# How to retrieve all the data from check boxes in request (django)?

Tags: python, django, select, checkbox

I have a form with the option to select multiple checkboxes, however when I try and retrieve the key from the dictionary in the post request.  It only provides the first value of the array(may not be an array).  I would like to retrieve all the data points.

Models

```
class CreateJournalistForm(forms.Form):

    vertical_choices = (('General', 'General'), ('News', 'News'), ('Life', 'Life'), ('Money', 'Money'), ('Sports', 'Sports'), ('Entertainment', 'Entertainment'), ('Dating', 'Dating'), ('Music', 'Music'), ('Humor', 'Humor'))

    name = forms.CharField(max_length=40, required=False)
    verticals = forms.MultipleChoiceField(required=True, widget=forms.CheckboxSelectMultiple, choices=vertical_choices)
    location = forms.CharField(max_length=40)
```

View

```
def journalist(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = CreateJournalistForm(request.POST)
        pdb.set_trace()
        if not form.data['name']:
            if form.is_valid():
                form.save()
                return HttpResponse("Thank you for applying.  We hope to get back to you soon")
            else:
                return HttpResponse("Sorry there was an error processing your application. Note: All fields on the application are required.")
        else:
            return HttpResponse("Thank you for applying.  We hope to get back to you soon")
    elif request.method == "GET":
        form = CreateJournalistForm()
    return render_to_response('journalist_application.html', {'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

In pry debugger request post will provide:

```
<QueryDict: {u'sample': [u'sdfsdf'], u'first_name': [u'sdfsd'], u'last_name': [u'sdfsf'], u'name': [u''], u'dob': [u'1/22/13'], u'twitter': [u'sdfsdf'], u'ideas': [u'sdfsdf'], u'contribution': [u'sdf'], u'verticals': [u'General', u'News', u'Life', u'Money', u'Sports'], u'google': [u'sdfsdf'], u'location': [u'sdfsdf']}
```

This is provided by request.POST in debugger.  Now if I provide the key request.POST['verticals'] it will only return one object in the array.  u'Sports'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know why you want to access the request directly, since you have a form and it is taking care of converting the params into an object.

However, you can use `request.POST.getlist('verticals')` to get all the values for a key.

Comment: that works! how might i use the form to get the data?

Comment: You should be using `form.cleaned_data` to access the data after form validation. This is all explained in the forms docs, as is the correct pattern to show errors to the user.